# Warning: React.jsx

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I have lots of error on Expo Go in react native with my ios device.

> iOS Bundling complete 2569ms
> ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)
> ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)
> ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)
> iOS Bundling complete 54ms
> ERROR  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)
> ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)
> ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)

```
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { firebase } from '../config';

const Fetch = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('todos');

    useEffect(async () => {
            todoRef
            .onSnapshot(
                querySnapshot => {
                    const users = []
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const { heading, text } = doc.data()
                        users.push({
                            id: doc.id,
                            heading,
                            text,
                        })

                    })
                    setUsers(users)

                }
            )


    }, [])


  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:100}}>

        <FlatList 
                style={{height:'100%'}}
                data={users}
                numColumns={1}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                    <Pressable
                        style={styles.container}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                            <Text  style={styles.itemHeading}>{item.heading}</Text>
                            <Text  style={styles.itemText}>{item.text}</Text>



                        </View>
                    
                    </Pressable>



                )}
        
        
        />

    </View>
  )
}

export default Fetch

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor:'e5e5e5',
        padding:15,
        borderRadius:15,
        margin:5,
        marginHorizontal:10,
     },
     innerContainer:{
        alignItems:'center',
        flexDirection:'column',
     },
     itemHeading:{
        fontWeight:'bold'
     },
     itemText:{
        fontWeight:'300'
     }


})
```